# Number of spanning trees of a graph with k multiple edges

Tags: graph-theory

Question:

Let $G$ be a simple graph on $n$ vertices, and let $H$ be the graph obtained from $G$ by replacing each edge of $G$ by $k$ multiple edges. Show that $t(H)=k^{n-1}t(G)$. (Here, $t(G)$ denotes the number of spanning trees.)

Attempt 1: Try to find the eigenvalues of the Laplacian matrix $L$ of $H$.

$L=D-A$ with $D$ the degree matrix of $H$ and $A$ the adjacency matrix of $H$

$$
D=k
\begin{bmatrix}
d(v_1) & 0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0\\
0 & d(v_2) & 0 & \cdots & \vdots\\
0 & \cdots & \ddots & \cdots & \vdots\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & d(v_n)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
D_1 & \boldsymbol{0}\\
\boldsymbol{0} & D_2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
A=k
\begin{bmatrix}
B_1^0 & B_2\\
B_3 & B_4^0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

with $B_i$ for $1\leq i\leq 4$ denoting Boolean matrices. The superscript $0$ denotes that the entries of the diagonal of the matrix are $0$s.

Thus,

$$
L=k
\begin{bmatrix}
D_1-B_1^0 & -B_2\\
-B_3 & D_2-B_4^0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Here's where I'm stuck: Trying to find the eigenvalues of $L$. I don't know if it's possible based on the given information.

Attempt 2: Using $t(G)=t(G\setminus e)+t(G/e)$ with $e$ a link of $G$.

Thus $t(H)=t(H\setminus e)+t(H/e)$; however, how would I find $t(H\setminus e)$ or $t(H/e)$? I'm not sure where to begin.

I am looking for hints in the right direction. Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Just to let you know, I'm getting my info from Bondy & Murty: GTM - Graph Theory.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few hints. (Suggestion: give each hint some thought before moving on to the next hint.)

Hint 1:

> Note that the Laplacians of $G$ and $H$ are related by a simple formula.

Hint 2:

> The relation is $L_H = k \cdot L_G$. This is all you need.

Hint 3:

> Alternative approach: let $T(G)$ denote the *set* of all spanning trees of $G$. Define $f : E(H) \to E(G)$ to be the function that forgets the multiple edges, i.e. that maps each of the $k$ parallel edges in $H$ between $v_1$ and $v_2$ to the unique edge in $G$ between $v_1$ and $v_2$. Then $f$ induces a function $F : T(H) \to T(G)$. How often does every spanning tree occur in the image of $F$?